# issue while exporting torch model to onnx format

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, onnx

I'm trying to export my PyTorch model to an ONNX format but I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

This is my code:

```py
model = Model(opt)
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)
file_path='/content/drive/MyDrive/VitSTR/vitstr_tiny_patch16_224_aug.pth'
torch.save(model.state_dict(), file_path)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(file_path))
#model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model).to(device)
#print(model)
torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "vitstr.onnx", verbose=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViTSTR [forward](https://github.com/roatienza/deep-text-recognition-benchmark/blob/c937d69388dbaa1c4a776badb2670344b39d0942/model.py#L79) requires two positional arguments, `input` and `text`:

```py
def forward(self, input, text, is_train=True, seqlen=25):
    # ...
```

Therefore, you need to pass an additional argument:

```py
# ...
dummy_text = # create a dummy_text as well, with the appropriate shape
torch.onnx.export(model, (dummy_input, dummy_text), "vitstr.onnx", verbose=True)
```

Comment: @RouaRouatbi that's not how SO works :) this is a different problem. Consider marking it as answer or upvoting if it helped you. Your new problem is easy to fix, but it should be a different question. Feel free to post a link to your new question here. Also, always post the complete traceback.